# How to match once per file in grep?

Tags: regex, perl, shell, unix, grep

Is there any grep option that let's me control total number of matches but stops at first match on each file?

Example:

If I do this `grep -ri --include '*.coffee' 're' .` I get this:

```
./app.coffee:express = require 'express'
./app.coffee:passport = require 'passport'
./app.coffee:BrowserIDStrategy = require('passport-browserid').Strategy
./app.coffee:app = express()
./config.coffee:    session_secret: 'nyan cat'
```

And if I do `grep -ri -m2 --include '*.coffee' 're' .`, I get this:

```
./app.coffee:config = require './config'
./app.coffee:passport = require 'passport'
```

But, what I really want is this output:

```
./app.coffee:express = require 'express'
./config.coffee:    session_secret: 'nyan cat'
```

Doing `-m1` does not work as I get this for `grep -ri -m1 --include '*.coffee' 're' .`

```
./app.coffee:express = require 'express'
```

Tried not using grep e.g. this `find . -name '*.coffee' -exec awk '/re/ {print;exit}' {} \;` produced:

```
config = require './config'
    session_secret: 'nyan cat'
```

**UPDATE: As noted below the GNU grep `-m` option treats counts per file whereas `-m` for BSD grep treats it as global match count**

Comment: Looking at this again, I don't see the first line of the text you "really want" in anywhere else.  Can you confirm what the first line with `re` is in your file, `./app.coffee` ?  Is it a `config =` line, or `express =` ?

Comment: TL;DR: `grep -m1` and this question is better suited for [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358523/find-only-the-first-occurence-using-only-grep).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think you can just do something like

```
grep -ri -m1 --include '*.coffee' 're' . | head -n 2
```

to e.g. pick the first match from each file, and pick at most two matches total.

Note that this requires your `grep` to treat `-m` as a per-file match limit; GNU `grep` does do this, but BSD `grep` apparently treats it as a global match limit.

Comment: `-m1` stops at first match globally for me. In any case, if there are millions of matches and I only want 100 of them then this is inefficient as the grep would still go for the first million matches before piping result into `head`

Comment: `head` stops reading input after the first hundred lines, and `grep` streams them match-by-match. After `head` stops reading input, `grep` will stop finding matches.

Comment: I just tried and it just prints the first result for me with or without the `| head -n 2` part. If I change option to `-m2` I see 2 results.

Comment: `-m` is clearly documented in my `man grep` as a per-file option...what `grep` are you using?

Comment: `grep --v` says `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD` on my Mountain Lion

Comment: Funny, I'm on Lion and my `/usr/bin/grep` is `grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1` (and it does per-file `-m`).

Comment: I can confirm, /usr/bin/grep on OS X 10.8.2 is `(BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD` and its `-m` is global, not per file.  GNU grep is per file.  nneonneo, you must have overwritten `/usr/bin` with GNU tools.  @wrick I'd suggest getting GNU tools, the BSD ones that OS X comes with are kinda janky.  It will make your life much easier in the long run.  Use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) or [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/).

Comment: @Schwern: I guess I must've, but I don't recall ever doing it :-\

Comment: @Schwern - I would NEVER recommend overwriting system-provided tools with GNU ones.  The system ones get updated by Apple.  Much better to put GNU tools in a different location, then adjust your $PATH accordingly.

Comment: The GNU one makes so much more sense than the BSD interpretation of `-m` IMO - thanks for catching this

Comment: @Graham I suspect you meant "I don't recommend overwriting".  MacPorts and Homebrew take care of all that, they live on their own paths and handle the environment adjustments.  Violent agreement.

Comment: OK, this is starting to get a bit weird. I consulted a friend, who also uses 10.7, and has GNU `grep` in `/usr/bin/grep`. Furthermore, the `man` page for `grep` on Apple's site says it's GNU `grep`. Did Apple suddenly change the default in 10.8?

Comment: @nneonneo Yep, I'm seeing complaints on the internet about grep being reverted to BSD in 10.8.  Reason number 230823 to use MacPorts or Homebrew.

Comment: Maybe you have an older Mac? Found this: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle/issues/41

Comment: @wrick: Yes I do. I have 10.7. So it seems that `grep` was indeed "downgraded" to BSD `grep` in 10.8.

Comment: FreeBSD has been using GNU grep 2.5.1 for years.  OSX pre 10.8 and 1.8 both use GNU grep 2.5.1 as well.  In FreeBSD 9.0 and OSX 10.8 the behaviour I see with `-m 1` is one line per file. @Schwern - please re-check your "confirmed" results, as I can't replicate them.

Comment: I confirm schwern's results - for me -m does this: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle/issues/41

Comment: @Graham Double check you're running /usr/bin/grep.  I can't find anything definitive, but my 10.8.2 machine has BSD grep as /usr/bin/grep and [there's](http://iosopendev.com/download/) [a lot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259484/grep-bsd-grep-2-5-1-freebsd-on-mac-os-10-8-line-regexp-mode-not-working-with-o) [of people](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4588476) [on the](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4588304) [internet](https://de.twitter.com/kokoabim/status/213796457046749184) [confirming](http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-dev/2012/Aug/msg00005.html).

Comment: @Schwern - here are my results in FreeBSD 9.0-RELEASE: http://pastebin.com/RiECy9CE  This is the same version of grep reported in OSX 10.8.  I don't have access to an OSX 10.8 box just at the moment, but I believe `-m1` would be treated the same way on it.  Do you see anything wrong with my test?

Comment: @Graham Your test is fine... except its using GNU grep. We know GNU grep works. The only point of contention is what OS X ships with. Prior to 10.8 it was GNU grep. 10.8 introduced BSD grep as confirmed on my machine and all the posts I linked to previously. `/usr/bin/grep --version` `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD` `uname -s -r` `Darwin 12.2.0`. Are you *sure* you're looking at `/usr/bin/grep` on your OS X 10.8 machine and you haven't overwritten it?

Comment: I, for one, have never heard of `-m` acting globally rather than per-file.  If this happens in OSX 10.8, it's an Apple-ism, not something to do with the port of GNU grep that is part of FreeBSD.  (Note that if there really is such a thing as "BSD grep"; it's not from FreeBSD.  FreeBSD still uses a port of GNU grep 2.5.1, as it (and OSX) has for years.)

Comment: Okay, I can confirm that OSX 10.8.2 behaves differently from FreeBSD.  @Schwern, sorry to doubt you, but as ghoti said, this isn't the how grep behaves in any BSD operating system I've seen before; it seems to be unique to OSX.

Answer (score 98):

So, using `grep`, you just need the option [`-l, --files-with-matches`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#index-_002d_002dfiles_002dwith_002dmatches).

All those answers about `find`, `awk` or shell scripts are away from the question.

Comment: This is the easiest method. For the lazy, the option `-l` is the abbreviation of `--files-with-matches`. So you don't need both.

Answer (score 4):

I would do this in `awk` instead.

```
find . -name \*.coffee -exec awk '/re/ {print FILENAME ":" $0;exit}' {} \;
```

If you didn't need to recurse, you could just do it with awk:

```
awk '/re/ {print FILENAME ":" $0;nextfile}' *.coffee
```

Or, if you're using a current enough bash, you can use globstar:

```
shopt -s globstar
awk '/re/ {print FILENAME ":" $0;nextfile}' **/*.coffee
```

Comment: Did not print as expected. Here's what I got:
`bash-3.2$ find . -name \*.coffee -exec awk '/re/ {print;exit}' {} \;

config = require './config'
   session_secret: 'nyan cat'`

Comment: One problem with that is, at least on my system, you can't really pipe the output of `find -exec` to `head`, because the `SIGPIPE` goes to the process that `find` launches, rather than to `find` itself, so it just keeps re-launching the program long after it's found two matches.

Comment: Updated the answer to include filenames, as well as globstar as an alternate way to recurse.  As for piping to `head`, why would you need to do that here?  I don't see a requirement for that in the question.  The `awk` script takes care of stopping after the first match in each file.

Comment: @wrick - just a note about globstar; I gather you're using an older `bash`, since your prompt is `base-3.2$`.  Globstar was added to bash in version 4.0.  You can either skip globstar, or install a more recent `bash` using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/). Also, I don't see the problem with your output.  While comments suck for code/output formatting, it appears you're seeing lines with `re` in them.  If you like, you can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12831417/edit) to include a better formatted result for this attempt.

Comment: Done - still did not work - did not print results from other file

Comment: @wrick, what was the output you were expecting?

Comment: I expect 1 unique file per line (question has what I expect). Thanks!

Comment: Well, I haven't seen your input, so I can't tell whether the output matches.  "re" is in "REquires", but it's also in "secREt".  Did you try with the updated `find` line that includes `FILENAME`?

Comment: @ghoti: Re: "As for piping to `head`, why would you need to do that here?": The question asks to "control total number of matches", and gives the example of `-m2` to limit the total number of matches to two.

Comment: Ah, right you are.  So the correct answer to the OP's initial question is simply "no".

Answer (score 2):

using find and xargs.
find every .coffee files and excute -m1 grep to each of them

```
find . -print0 -name '*.coffee'|xargs -0 grep -m1 -ri 're'
```

test
 without -m1

```
linux# find . -name '*.txt'|xargs grep -ri 'oyss'
./test1.txt:oyss
./test1.txt:oyss1
./test1.txt:oyss2
./test2.txt:oyss1
./test2.txt:oyss2
./test2.txt:oyss3
```

add -m1

```
linux# find . -name '*.txt'|xargs grep -m1 -ri 'oyss'
./test1.txt:oyss
./test2.txt:oyss1
```

Comment: This won't work if there are special characters in filenames.  See [the parsing ls problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @Graham Use `find -print0` and `xargs -0`, as in my answer, to get around that.

Comment: @Graham: easily amended, use `find -print0` and `xargs -0`.

Comment: This solution shares nneonneo's problem, it only works on GNU grep.  BSD grep's -m is global, not per file.

Comment: @Graham example please.I'm not familiar with this issue. simply test with filenames like test1?.txt still ok.

Comment: @Schwern xargs is per file. the grep is executed on each file find matches. there should not be an global -m issue.

Comment: @oyss - create a file with `touch foo.coffee\ bar.coffee`.  It's a single file, with a space in the filename.  Using xargs the way you've suggested, xargs will interpret it as two files.  Check the link on my first comment for more details.

Comment: @oyss Tested it with the BSD and GNU greps on my system.  I think I see the confusion.  xargs does not call the command once for each file, but just once with a list of files.  Only if xargs thinks the file list is going to overflow the exec buffer will it do multiple calls.  You can test this by writing a program which prints each time it starts and then prints all its arguments.

Answer (score 2):

`find . -name \*.coffee -exec grep -m1 -i 're' {} \;`

find's -exec option runs the command once for each matched file (unless you use `+` instead of `\;`, which makes it act like xargs).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily in perl, and no messy cross platform issues!

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $match = shift;

# Compile the match so it will run faster
my $match_re = qr{$match};

FILES: for my $file (@ARGV) {
    open my $fh, "<", $file;

    FILE: while(my $line = <$fh>) {
        chomp $line;

        if( $line =~ $match_re ) {
            print "$file: $line\n";
            last FILE;
        }
    }
}
```

The only difference is you have to use Perl style regular expressions instead of GNU style.  [They're not much different](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html).

You can do the recursive part in Perl using [File::Find](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aFind), or use `find` feed it files.

```
find /some/path -name '*.coffee' -print0 | xargs -0 perl /path/to/your/program
```