# List files that contain `n` or fewer lines

Tags: bash, performance, shell, file, awk

## Question

In a folder, I would like to print the name of every `.txt` files that contain `n=27` lines or fewer lines. I could do

```
wc -l *.txt | awk '{if ($1 <= 27){print}}'
```

The problem is that many files in the folder are millions of lines (and the lines are pretty long) and hence the command `wc -l *.txt` is very slow. In principle a process could count the number of lines until finding at least `n` lines and then proceed to the next file.

**What is a faster alternative?**

FYI, I am on `MAC OSX 10.11.6`

## Attempt

Here is an attempt with `awk`

```
#!/bin/awk -f

function printPreviousFileIfNeeded(previousNbLines, previousFILENAME)
{
  if (previousNbLines <= n) 
  {
    print previousNbLines": "previousFILENAME
  }
}

BEGIN{
  previousNbLines=n+1
  previousFILENAME=NA
} 


{
  if (FNR==1)
  {
    printPreviousFileIfNeeded(previousNbLines, previousFILENAME)
    previousFILENAME=FILENAME
  }
  previousNbLines=FNR
  if (FNR > n)
  {
    nextfile
  }
}

END{
  printPreviousFileIfNeeded(previousNbLines, previousFILENAME)
}
```

which can be called as

```
awk -v n=27 -f myAwk.awk *.txt
```

However, the code fails at printing out perfectly empty files. I am not sure how to fix that and I am not sure my awk script is the way to go.

Comment: head -n27  *txt | wc  -l | awk '{if ($1 <= 27){print}}'

Comment: @newbie That also won't handle empty files.

Comment: it does on bash linux , it returns 0 ?  head -n27 empty.txt | wc -l 
0

Comment: Oh right, but you need to run it in a loop, one file at a time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With GNU awk for nextfile and ENDFILE:

```
awk -v n=27 'FNR>n{f=1; nextfile} ENDFILE{if (!f) print FILENAME; f=0}' *.txt
```

With any awk:

```
awk -v n=27 '
    { fnrs[FILENAME] = FNR }
    END {
        for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) {
            filename = ARGV[i]
            if ( fnrs[filename] < n ) {
                print filename
            }
        }
    }
' *.txt
```

Those will both work whether the input files are empty or not. The caveats for the non-gawk version are the same as for your other current awk answers:

1. It relies on the same file name not appearing multiple times (e.g. `awk 'script' foo bar foo`) and you wanting it displayed multiple times, and
2. It relies on there being no variables set in the arg list (e.g. `awk 'script' foo FS=, bar`)

The gawk version has no such restrictions.

**UPDATE:**

To test the timing between the above GNU awk script and [the GNU grep+sed script posted by xhienne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52633562/1745001) since she stated that her solution would be `faster than a pure awk script` I created 10,000 input files, all of 0 to 1000 lines in length by using this script:

```
$ awk -v numFiles=10000 -v maxLines=1000 'BEGIN{for (i=1;i<=numFiles;i++) {numLines=int(rand()*(maxLines+1)); out="out_"i".txt"; printf "" > out; for (j=1;j<=numLines; j++) print ("foo" j) > out} }'
```

and then ran the 2 commands on them and got these 3rd run timing results:

```
$ time grep -c -m28 -H ^ *.txt | sed '/:28$/ d; s/:[^:]*$//' > out.grepsed

real    0m1.326s
user    0m0.249s
sys     0m0.654s

$ time awk -v n=27 'FNR>n{f=1; nextfile} ENDFILE{if (!f) print FILENAME; f=0}' *.txt > out.awk

real    0m1.092s
user    0m0.343s
sys     0m0.748s
```

Both scripts produced the same output files. The above was run in bash on cygwin. I expect on different systems the timing results might vary a little but the difference will always be negligible.

---

To print 10 lines of up to 20 random chars per line (see the comments):

```
$ maxChars=20
    LC_ALL=C tr -dc '[:print:]' </dev/urandom |
    fold -w "$maxChars" |
    awk -v maxChars="$maxChars" -v numLines=10 '
        { print substr($0,1,rand()*(maxChars+1)) }
        NR==numLines { exit }
    '
0J)-8MzO2V\XA/o'qJH
@r5|g<WOP780
^O@bM\
vP{l^pgKUFH9
-6r&]/-6dl}pp W
&.UnTYLoi['2CEtB
Y~wrM3>4{
^F1mc9
?~NHh}a-EEV=O1!y
of
```

To do it all within awk (which will be much slower):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    for (i=32; i<127; i++) {
        chars[++charsSize] = sprintf("%c",i)
    }
    minChars = 1
    maxChars = 20
    srand()
    for (lineNr=1; lineNr<=10; lineNr++) {
        numChars = int(minChars + rand() * (maxChars - minChars + 1))
        str = ""
        for (charNr=1; charNr<=numChars; charNr++) {
            charsIdx = int(1 + rand() * charsSize)
            str = str chars[charsIdx]
        }
        print str
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk
Heer H{QQ?qHDv|
Psuq
Ey`-:O2v7[]|N^EJ0
j#@/y>CJ3:=3*b-joG:
?
^|O.[tYlmDo
TjLw
`2Rs=
!('IC
hui
```

Comment: '@Ed fantastic way of generating files using awk oneliner.. is there a way to generate random text data in the place of "foo" ?

Comment: @stack0114106 I just updated my answer to show a couple of options for generating random strings.

Comment: Thanks @Ed..you built the ascii array starting at 32 and ensured no control characters in the output.

Comment: Is your cygwin platform limited in the number of CPUs allocated to it? If so please test the sequential version of my script. All in all, I'm glad you did (and published) your benchmarks, since your results somewhat confirm my assertion; however, I bet that we probably don't look at the same lines in the output of `time`. As promised, I did my own benchmarks and added the results to my answer.

Comment: I really have no idea on cygwin limits on the CPUs, sorry. Sounds like you've done some comprehensive benchmarking so - great, thanks for doing that.

Comment: @EdMorton I tried the _any awk_ version with the dataset created with your script but it didn't output anything. It did run about 2 seconds (as opposed to the _gnu awk_ version which ran 0.3 secs on my laptop).

Comment: @JamesBrown I hadn't shown `-v n=27` being set on the command line for that one, I've added it now.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using GNU `grep` (unfortunately MacOSX >= 10.8 provides BSD grep whose `-m` and `-c` options [act globally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12831475/7233423), not per file), you may find this alternative interesting (and faster than a pure `awk` script):

```
grep -c -m28 -H ^ *.txt | sed '/:28$/ d; s/:[^:]*$//'
```

Explanation:

- `grep -c -m28 -H ^ *.txt` outputs the name of each file with the number of lines in each file, but never reading more than 28 lines
- `sed '/:28$/ d; s/:[^:]*$//'` removes the files that have at least 28 lines, and print the filename of the others

Alternate version: sequential processing instead of a parallel one

```
res=$(grep -c -m28 -H ^ $files); sed '/:28$/ d; s/:[^:]*$//' <<< "$res"
```

---

### Benchmarking

Ed Morton challenged my claim that this answer may be faster than `awk`. He added some benchmarks to his answer and, although he does not give any conclusion, I consider the results he posted are misleading, showing a greater wall-clock time for my answer without any regard to user and sys times. Therefore, here are my results.

First the test platform:

- A four-core Intel i5 laptop running Linux, probably quite close to OP's system (Apple iMac).
- A brand new directory of 100.000 text files with ~400 lines in average, for a total of 640 MB which is kept entirely in my system buffers. The files were created with this command:

  ```
  for ((f = 0; f < 100000; f++)); do echo "File $f..."; for ((l = 0; l < RANDOM & 1023; l++)); do echo "File $f; line $l"; done > file_$f.txt; done
  ```

Results:

- grep+sed (this answer) : 561 ms elapsed, 586 ms user+sys
- grep+sed (this answer, sequential version) : 678 ms elapsed, 688 ms user+sys
- [awk (Ed Morton)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52634011/7233423): 1050 ms elapsed, 1036 ms user+sys
- [awk (tripleee)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52632903/7233423): 1137 ms elapsed, 1123 ms user+sys
- [awk (anubhava)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52632814/7233423): 1150 ms elapsed, 1137 ms user+sys
- [awk (kvantour)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52650384/7233423): 1280 ms elapsed, 1266 ms user+sys
- [python (Joey Harrington)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52633351/7233423): 1543 ms elapsed, 1537 ms user+sys
- [find+xargs+sed (agc)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52635924/7233423): 91 s elapsed, 10 s user+sys
- [for+awk (Jeff Schaller)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52633039/7233423): 247 s elapsed, 83 s user+sys
- [find+bash+grep (hek2mgl)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52635479/7233423): 356 s elapsed, 116 s user+sys

Conclusion:

At the time of writing, on a regular Unix multi-core laptop similar to OP's machine, this answer is the fastest that gives accurate results. On my machine, it is twice as fast as the fastest awk script.

Notes:

- Why does the platform matter? Because my answer relies on parallelizing the processing between `grep` and `sed`. Of course, for unbiased results, if you have only one CPU core (VM?) or other limitations by your OS regarding CPU allocation, you should benchmark the alternate (sequential) version.
- Obviously, you can't conclude on the wall time alone since it depends on the number of concurrent processes asking for the CPU vs the number of cores on the machine. Therefore I have added the user+sys timings
- Those timings are an average over 20 runs, except when the command took more than 1 minute (one run only)
- For all the answers that take less than 10 s, the time spent by the shell to process `*.txt` is not negligible, therefore I preprocessed the file list, put it in a variable, and appended the content of the variable to the command I was benchmarking.
- All answers gave the same results except 1. tripleee's answer which includes `argv[0]` ("awk") in its result (fixed in my tests); 2. kvantour's answer which only listed empty files (fixed with `-v n=27`); and 3. the find+sed answer which miss empty files (not fixed).
- I couldn't test [ctac_'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52635477/7233423) since I have no GNU sed 4.5 at hand. It is probably the fastest of all but also misses empty files.
- The python answer doesn't close its files. I had to do `ulimit -n hard` first.

Comment: IMHO this is a good solution so +1 for that but wrt your claim that your grep+sed solution would be faster than a pure awk script, I created a test set of 10,000 files each of 0 to 1,000 lines to test your grep+sed vs my awk and posted the result in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52634011/1745001).

Comment: I seriously question your results (not your honesty, just the results). You should really test on a real multi-core Unix platform, not on Cygwin. I already noticed similar results 10 years ago.

Comment: For better or worse the cygwin platform I tested on is the platform I run most of my shell scripts on so the timing results I get there are the only ones that matter to me personally. Thanks for doing the benchmarking on those other platforms.

Comment: Ah, well spotted. `$ time { res=$(grep -c -m28 -H ^ *.txt); sed '/:28$/ d; s/:[^:]*$//' <<< "$res" > out.sed; }` outputs `real    0m0.889s
user    0m0.248s
sys     0m0.624s
`

Comment: The `-m` option doesn't do what you expect my Mac. It only prints the first 28 matches, not the first 28 each file; and with `-c` it prints just the  number 28 for the first input file.

Comment: Thank you @tripleee, I have amended my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You may try this `awk` that moves to next file as soon as line count goes above `27`:

```
awk -v n=27 'BEGIN{for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) f[ARGV[i]]}
FNR > n{delete f[FILENAME]; nextfile}
END{for (i in f) print i}' *.txt
```

`awk` processes files line by line so it won't attempt to read complete file to get the line count.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this would fail to print empty files, is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Do you want to print empty filenames as well?

Comment: Yes please :) They have less than `n` lines. Note that in the post it is  highlighted that my attempt fail at listing empty files too. tripleee came up with a solution involving setting up the has map in a BEGIN block. Thank you!

Comment: Wow, just realized a very similar answer from my friend tripleee

Answer (score 3):

How's this?

```
awk 'BEGIN { for(i=1;i<ARGC; ++i) arg[ARGV[i]] }
  FNR==28 { delete arg[FILENAME]; nextfile }
  END { for (file in arg) print file }' *.txt
```

We copy the list of file name arguments to an associative array, then remove all files which have a 28th line from it. Empty files obviously won't match this condition, so at the end, we are left with all files which have fewer lines, including the empty ones.

`nextfile` was a common extension in many Awk variants and then was codified by POSIX in 2012. If you need this to work on really old dinosaur OSes (or, good heavens, probably Windows), good luck, and/or try GNU Awk.

Comment: I was baffled to see how similar this is to Anubhava's answer, which appeared whrle I was composing this. The similarities are incidental, honest. And the difference is that this should capture empty files, too.

Comment: Just wondering about your statement that `nextfile` is part of POSIX. I cannot find any reference to that in the posix standard (the only mention I find about this is the link on the GNU awk page). Are you certain about this statement?

Comment: The POSIX information comes from the [GNU Awk documentation for `nextfile`;](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nextfile-Statement.html) it actually says "accepted for inclusion in 2012" so maybe that means the process was initiated then?

Comment: @kvantour Thanks for the `ARGC` fix; updated the script.

Comment: @kvantour The fix is incorrect. `ARGV[0]` is "awk". That should be `for(i=1; i<ARGC; ++i)`

Answer (score 3):

While [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) seems to be the most interesting way to proceed, here is yet another one to the already existing solutions of [triplee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52632903/8344060), [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52632814/8344060) and [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52634011/8344060). Where to solutions of triplee and anubhava make use of the `nextfile` statement and Ed Morton's POSIX proof solution is reading full files, I provide a solution that is not reading the full files.

```
awk -v n=27 'BEGIN{ for(i=1;i<ARGC;++i) {
                       j=0; fname=ARGV[i];
                       while( ((getline < fname) > 0 ) && j<=n) { j++ }
                       if(j<=n) print fname; close(fname)
                  }
                  exit
             }' *.txt
```

Comment: You should make it `while( ((getline < fname) > 0) && j<=n)` so it doesn't keep looping if/when the getline fails. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline. Otherwise, though - nice and appropriate use of getline! It does still rely on there being no variables set in the arg list of course `awk '...' file1 FS=, file2`. Actually - in this case that getline bug might save you from outputting the wrong thing when `FS=,` occurs in the arg list, assuming there isn't a file named `FS=,` in your working directory :-).

Comment: @Ed. This is interesting. I had to change `n=27` to `-v n=27` for this script to work, but was unable to understand why.

Comment: Unlike when you set them with `-v`, variables aren't set in the BEGIN section when you set them in the arg list, the `n=27` only takes effect AFTER the BEGIN section has been processed so `n` isn't populated during your loop.

Comment: @EdMorton Exactly, it worked as if n=0. But why does it seem to work for kvantour?

Comment: @EdMorton I did test it, but had the value hardcoded, afterwards I added the n=27 to remove the hardcoded value. My mistake. But yes, the n=27 is invalid and should be in front of it as `-v n=27`

Comment: @xhienne exactly, it should be `-v n=27` or declare it in the `BEGIN` statment for the reasons Ed Morton stated.

Answer (score 1):

with sed (GNU sed) 4.5 :

```
sed -n -s '28q;$F' *.txt
```

Comment: Too bad that I can't test it and add it to my benchmarks. I bet this would be the fastest answer. Unfortunately, your script is missing empty files since it requires that the input files have at least one line.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with [`sed` *v4.5-1* from *Debian Sid*](http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/sed/sed_4.5-1_amd64.deb), it just quit after the first file, like previous versions of `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` with the help of a little bash inline script:

```
find -type f -exec bash -c '[ $(grep -cm 28 ^ "${1}") != "28" ] && echo "${1}"' -- {} \;
```

The command `[ $(grep -cm 28 ^ "${1}") != "28" ] && echo "${1}"` uses grep to search for the begin of a line (`^`) at maximum 28 times. If that command returns != "28", the file must have more less than 28 lines.

Comment: You are exec'ing one bash and one grep process for each file found; this is terribly slow! (see the benchmarks I added to my answer). If you change your answer to process several files at once, I'll be glad to re-benchmark your code.

Comment: Giving the fastest solution was not my intention. I just wanted to join the party :) (I overlooked your answer, otherwise I wouldn't have posted mine)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to call awk individually, ask it to stop at line 28:

```
for f in ./*.txt
do
  if awk 'NR > 27 { fail=1; exit; } END { exit fail; }' "$f"
  then
    printf '%s\n' "$f"
  fi
done
```

The default value of awk variables is zero, so if we never hit line 28, the exit code is zero, making the `if` test successful, and so prints the filename.

Comment: the OP stated that they don't want to read the whole files ("The problem is that many files in the folder are millions of lines").

Comment: Whoops; I think I missed an exit in the >27 case. Will fix later.

Comment: Added the `exit`, though a shell loop calling awk multiple times will always be slower than an awk that can process multiple files. I'll leave this here in case it's helpful for someone without GNU awk.

Answer (score 0):

`python -c "import sys; print '\n'.join([of.name for of in [open(fn) for fn in sys.argv[1:]] if len(filter(None, [of.readline() for _ in range(28)])) <= 27])" *.txt`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Software tools and *GNU* `sed` (older versions before *v4.5*) mashup:

```
find *.txt -print0 | xargs -0 -L 1 sed -n '28q;$F'
```

That misses 0-byte files, to include those as well, do:

```
find *.txt \( -exec sed -n '28{q 1}' '{}' \; -or -size 0 \) -print
```

(For some reason running `sed` via `-exec` is about *12%* slower than `xargs`.)

---

`sed` code stolen from [*ctac*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52635477/6136214).

Note:  On my own system's older `sed` *v4.4-2*, the `q`*uit* command combined with the `--separate` switch doesn't just quit the current file, it quits `sed` entirely. Which means it requires a separate instance of `sed` for every file.

Comment: Unfortunately, your script is missing empty files since it requires (`$F`) the input files to have at least one line. Moreover, launching one `sed` command per file is really resource-hungry and cannot compete with the other scripts that only use one or two commands.

Comment: @xhienne, Thanks, I hadn't noticed the empty file bug.  Agreed that's it's not efficient, but when there's not too much data it won't make much difference.  And when memory is very low, `sed` uses less of it; compare `ls -l $(realpath $(which sed awk))`

Comment: Agreed, but OP has no low memory constraint (iMac) and is explicitly looking for a faster alternative to `wc -l *.txt | awk '{if ($1 <= 27){print}}'`

Comment: @xhienne, I'm not anti-`awk`, but...  1) This question is somewhat general, so there probably are, or eventually will be, other readers here besides the OP, who have their own needs.  2) `sed` is faster here than `wc`, since each file quits after no more than 28 lines, whereas `wc` will read a big file to the end.

Comment: @xhienne, Also, thanks for [running those benchmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52633562/6136214), which I hadn't seen before now, and which really show the efficiency hit.