# Reading grep patterns from a file with '-x' (exact line match) ... does pattern order matter?

Tags: macos, grep

New to using grep, and having a weird issue that's got me stumped. I created two identical files:

test1.txt

```
foo
foo bar
```

test2.txt

```
foo
foo bar
```

When I run `grep -x -f test1.txt test2.txt`, I expect to get `foo` and `foo bar`, but all I get is `foo`. But then, if I switch the order of the patterns in test1.txt as follows:

test1.txt

```
foo bar
foo
```

Now, when I run `grep -x -f test1.txt test2.txt`, I get what I want: `foo` and `foo bar`. Why? :( Also, is there a way to make this work without re-arranging the order of the patterns? (This is part of a larger project, and there are many examples of this.) Thank you!

Comment: What OS is it? I assume it's Linux?

Comment: I tried the same thing but get the expected answer... can you try     grep -x -f text1.txt text1.txt

Comment: Tried `grep -x -f test1.txt test1.txt` and still got only `foo`. However, after switching the order of the patterns, running `grep -x -f test1.txt test1.txt` gives what I want: `foo bar` and `foo`.

Comment: @andros Do `cat -vet` on both files and look for trailing spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Checked though, and no trailing spaces.

Comment: Using `-e` does the same thing. `grep -x -e "foo" -e "foo bar" test2.txt` gives `foo` and `grep -x -e "foo bar" -e "foo" test2.txt` gives `foo` and `foo bar`. I can't figure out why either.

Answer (score 3):

### Mac OSX with grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD

It looks like a bug in BSD grep, here is a related topic also: [grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD on mac os 10.8 line regexp mode not working with overlapping patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259484/grep-bsd-grep-2-5-1-freebsd-on-mac-os-10-8-line-regexp-mode-not-working-with-o)

I have the same version of grep (grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD) on my Mac OSX 10.9.1 and it behaves exactly the same.

### Ubuntu Precise with GNU grep

Works as expected.

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ grep -V
grep (GNU grep) 2.10
(...details removed...)
vagrant@precise64:~$ echo -e 'foo\nfoo bar' > test1.txt && cp test1.txt test2.txt
vagrant@precise64:~$ grep -x -f test1.txt test2.txt
foo
foo bar
```

### Mac OSX with GNU grep

Works as expected.

```
$ ggrep -V
ggrep (GNU grep) 2.14.56-1e3d
(...details removed...)
$ ggrep -x -f test1.txt test2.txt
foo
foo bar
```

---

---

**Sulution #1:**

If you really have to use BSD grep on Mac OSX, here is something that actually works:

```
$ grep -V
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
$ grep -e "^foo$" -e "^foo bar$" test2.txt
foo
foo bar
```

**Sulution #2:**

Install GNU grep via homebrew:

```
$ brew tap homebrew/dupes
Cloning into '/usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew-dupes'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 1083, done.
remote: Counting objects: 9, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Total 1092 (delta 3), reused 8 (delta 2)
Receiving objects: 100% (1092/1092), 216.09 KiB | 278.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (559/559), done.
Checking connectivity... done
Tapped 39 formula
$ brew install grep
(...installing...)
usr/local/Cellar/grep/2.15: 13 files, 872K, built in 40 seconds
```

It will be installed as `ggrep` this way. There are ways to install as `grep` also, or replace system grep, I wouldn't do that though (this is offtopic).
Anyway after installing:

```
$ which ggrep
/usr/local/bin/ggrep
```