# Grepping from a file does not return matches to string ...B if string ... is present in the file before ...B

Tags: bash, grep

I have reproduced my problem with a two line input file 'test':

```
RBMS3
RBMS3B
```

And this file to search 'database':

```
...."RBMS3"
...."RBMS3B"
```

My desired outcome is to find both of these lines.

Using this file 'test' I input:

```
grep -wf test database > out.txt
```

When 'test' is ordered as above, 'out.txt' contains only the line

```
...."RBMS3"
```

When 'test' is ordered with "RBSM3B" first, 'out.txt' contains both lines (the desired output)

My question is why this ordering matters and if there is flag for grep such that the ordering does not matter.

Thank you

Comment: What implementation and version of grep?

Comment: It smells like a bug. Seems like it's finding a match of the first pattern, but it's not a complete word that matches, so it fails and instead of checking the other patterns, just goes on to the next input line.

Comment: Thank you, I found out that it is indeed a bug in my version of grep

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer here: [grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD on mac os 10.8 line regexp mode not working with overlapping patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259484/grep-bsd-grep-2-5-1-freebsd-on-mac-os-10-8-line-regexp-mode-not-working-with-o)

It seems to be a bug with grep on Mac OS

Comment: Did you consider installing GNU grep on your Mac?

Comment: Yes, I've installed it now to avoid this in future